# Custom JtextField proprety

Tags: java

I've created a custom `JtextField` but any proprety defined method don't working like getText or SetText when I call it in the main `JFrame`.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class JTextFieldDecimal extends JTextField {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public JTextFieldDecimal()
{
    super();
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c =e.getKeyChar();
            if(!((c>='0') && (c<='9') || 
                    (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
                    (c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))
            {
                getToolkit().beep();
                e.consume();
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

[image]

when I click in validation button in jframe Produit the compiler give me an error and point to line 98 wich content my statement parameter of Custom JtextField named **txtPrixHT**.

```
btnValider.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Connection cn=null;
            PreparedStatement pst =null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/gesticom", "root","");
                //String sqlAdd ="insert into produit (PrCodeBarre,PrDesignation,PrPrixHT,PrRemise,PrPrixAchat,PrStockAlerte,PrStockReel) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                String sqlAdd ="insert into produit (PrCodeBarre,PrDesignation,PrPrixHT) values (?,?,?)";
                pst=cn.prepareStatement(sqlAdd,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                pst.setString(1, txtCodebarre.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtDesignation.getText());
                pst.setString(3,txtPrixHT.getText());
                pst.execute();
                rs=pst.getGeneratedKeys();
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    txtIdprod.setText(rs.getString(1));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nouveau Produit créé", "Fournisseur",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try
                {
                    cn.close();
                    pst.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The error doesn't occur in this part of the code, please add the relevant part of the `Produit` class (including the line 98 ) .

Comment: By the way, I would not mess to much with the `JTextField` key adapter. You consume the event but are you sure you have the priority ? `JTextField` use a `Document` to manage the input if I remember it correctly.

Comment: `txtPrixHT` must be `null` at line 98 .

Comment: I had fill txtPrixHT by value it's not null

Comment: Use the debugger to make sure this is using the `txtPrixHT` instance that is added to the GUI. If this is the line that throw the NPE, this is the most obvious reason.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative to your formatted text field, I would propose you don't try to validate the input yourself. You can use a `JFormattedTextField` that allow you to do it for you when the focus is lost. Here is a quick sample

```
JFormattedTextField decimalTxt = new JFormattedTextField(
    new NumberFormatter()
);
```

This will use the `Locale` of the JVM to format the number like expected (simpler for Decimal values). If you want only to take integers, provide an integer format

```
JFormattedTextField decimalTxt = new JFormattedTextField(
    new NumberFormatter(
        NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()
    )
);
```

You want to always have two decimal digit like `5.00`, define it in the `NumberFormat` :

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

JFormattedTextField decimalTxt = new JFormattedTextField(
    new NumberFormatter(nf)
);
```

You can find more information about this on [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: thank for answers deer dev, i do miske when i declare my Custom JtextField, my Error at: JTextFieldDecimaltxtPrixHT = new JTextFieldDecimal() then the first word JTextFieldDecimaltxtPrixHT  in declaration must be removed

Comment: @ITdevjava you forgot a space ... `JTextFieldDecimaltxtPrixHT` > `JTextFieldDecimal txtPrixHT` for the rest, I don't understand your problem.